# Wait loop on two conditions using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, loops, if-statement

I need the macro to loop if one of the criteria is not met. Working with some basic scraping. I need this to loop until ready before I start gathering data.

```
If ie.document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").Length < 1 Or ie.document.getElementsByClassName("feedback").Length < 1 Then
Do: Loop
End If
```

Comment: Why not use a Do while loop ?

Comment: Because when I get to the page there will be two different reports that will appear. One if it contains data. And one if it do not. But it will load after everything else so I will have to wait for one or the other.

Comment: Did my answer below work? I think either of the 2 answers given will work doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would look like this :

```
Do While ie.document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").Length >= 1 And ie.document.getElementsByClassName("feedback").Length >= 1
 '''code
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop does not check with each iteration, only once and if it is not ready then it will enter an infinite loop. You need a solution that checks each time the loop iterates.

```
Do
    If ie.document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").Length < 1 Or ie.document.getElementsByClassName("feedback").Length < 1 Then
        DoEvents 'free the processor to work on other things
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

This will check each time the loop iterates rather than just once.